# SPARQL query universities

Tags: sparql

I am trying to fetch the names of universities using SPARQL:

The rdf data is the following (and a whole lot more, but that is irrelevant).

```
<Organization rdf:about="http://data.semanticweb.org/organization/the-university-of-queensland">
    <rdfs:label>The University of Queensland</rdfs:label>
    <homepage rdf:resource="http://www.uq.edu.au/"/>
    <member rdf:resource="http://data.semanticweb.org/person/jane-hunter"/>
    <member rdf:resource="http://data.semanticweb.org/person/kwok-cheung"/>
    <member rdf:resource="http://data.semanticweb.org/person/robert-m-colomb"/>
    <name>The University of Queensland</name>
</Organization>
```

I have written a java program which queries the data. 
My string to query the data is the following:

```
            queryString += "PREFIX swrc:        <http://swrc.ontoware.org/ontology#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX dc:          <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX foaf:        <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX geo:         <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX ical:        <http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/ical#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX rdf:         <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX rdfs:        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX swc:         <http://data.semanticweb.org/ns/swc/ontology#> \n";
            queryString += "PREFIX swrc_ext:    <http://www.cs.vu.nl/~mcaklein/onto/swrc_ext/2005/05#> \n";
            queryString += "SELECT ?name WHERE {\n";
            queryString += "?university rdfs:label ?aff . \n ?university foaf:name ?name FILTER(str(?aff)='uni') }";
```

Unfortunately, this is not correct, as no result is returned:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
  <sparql xmlns='w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'> 
    <head> 
     <variable name='name'/> 
    </head> 
    <results> 
    </results> 
  </sparql>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

P.S. If possible I'd like to only fetch 10 university names.

Comment: SPARQL allows you to limit the number of results. Just append your query with `LIMIT 10`. What exactly is wrong with your result?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It is supposed to show the names of all universities. Unfortunatelly; this is the result:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
 <head>
  <variable name='name'/>
 </head>
 <results>
 </results>
</sparql>

Comment: I see, so there's no university that matches your criteria. I understand that you're assuming all universities have the string `'uni'` in their names. Try replacing `FILTER(str(?aff)='uni')` with `FILTER regex(?aff, "uni", "i")` or `FILTER regex(str(?aff), "uni", "i")`. Still, filtering by name seems like an odd approach to me. Doesn't the data set you're using provide this kind of information as a separate property?  It would make sense to classify organizations like this.

Comment: I asked myself that question too, by my tutor said there was no such thing available in the assignment, so I'd have to check the stuff like this.

Comment: I see. Did the `regex` filter help?

Comment: I just checked it. It turned out that the regex itself did not help. However. changing "uni" to "Uni" did! Which I only noticed thanks to you.

Thank you so much, aswell for the Limit thing!

Comment: Can you answer the question please, so that I can accept it? :)

Comment: That's odd. The regex is supposed to be case insensitive (given the "i" argument).

Comment: I changed it to Uni, while using the regex. So I'm not sure if it was because of the U or because of the regex; anyway it is working :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand that you're assuming all universities have the string `"uni"` in their names.

Notice that you're checking for equality of a value with the string `"uni"`. There really is no such instance in your data set.

Replacing `FILTER(str(?aff)='uni')` with `FILTER regex(?aff, "uni", "i")` will allow you to match the values that *contain* the string `"uni`" instead. It's a regular expression filter that takes three arguments.

1. a variable
2. a regular expression compliant with the syntax described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax)
3. a set of optional flags, in this case, I used one flag, `"i"`. It means the match must be case-insensitive.

In order to limit the number of results, you can just append the query with the `LIMIT` keyword.

The resulting query should be:

```
PREFIX swrc:        <http://swrc.ontoware.org/ontology#>
PREFIX dc:          <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf:        <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo:         <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX ical:        <http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/ical#>
PREFIX rdf:         <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:        <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX swc:         <http://data.semanticweb.org/ns/swc/ontology#>
PREFIX swrc_ext:    <http://www.cs.vu.nl/~mcaklein/onto/swrc_ext/2005/05#>
SELECT ?name WHERE {
    ?university rdfs:label ?aff . 
    ?university foaf:name ?name 
    FILTER regex(?aff, "uni", "i")
} LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your RDF snippet  does not have the "foaf:" namespace. So, maybe you should put  in your RDF. Unless of course it is the default namespace in your RDF document.